# Printing list items as integer

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

So I have some code that reads a file that contains score in this format:

```
lenard  1 
max 1
lenard  1
max 5
zack    3
max 4
james   4
zack    3
zack    3
james   4
eddie   7
james   4
eddie   7
eddie   7
lenard  4
lenard  10
```

I have code that takes the highest score for each name and outputs it from highest to lowest:

```
data = {}
alpha={}
with open('StudentsScoreA.txt') as fobj:
    for line in fobj:           #
        name, score = line.split()
        data.setdefault(name, []).append(int(score))

for name, scores in sorted(data.items()):
    highest = scores[-1:]
    alpha.update({name:highest})
    print(alpha)

for x in sorted(alpha, key=alpha.get, reverse=True):
    print('{} your score was {}'.format(x, alpha[x))
```

The program works but the outputs is not correct:

```
lenard your score was [10]
eddie your score was [7]
max your score was [4]
james your score was [4]
zack your score was [3]
```

I was wondering how i would make it print out like :

```
lenard your score was 10
```

I did try to do this by doing this instead :

```
highest = ''.join(str(item) for item in highest)
```

Whilst this does output it nicer the program does not print it out in a sorted order. How would I fix?

Comment: Did you mean `[-1]` (last item) rather than `[-1:]` (list slice starting at last item)?

Comment: No I mean [-1:] I only need the highest score of the student

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [-1] intead of [-1:]
The slice syntax (in list) will always return a list

[1,2,3,4] [-1] => 4

```
for name, scores in sorted(data.items()):
    highest = scores[-1] #was scores[-1:]
    alpha.update({name:highest})
    print(alpha)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the highest score then use the [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> data = defaultdict(list)
>>> with open('StudentsScoreA.txt') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         name, score = line.split()
...         data[name].append(int(score))
... 
>>> for name, score in data.items():
...     print('{} your score was {}'.format(name, max(score)))
... 
eddie your score was 7
lenard your score was 10
max your score was 5
james your score was 4
zack your score was 3
```